# Android Studio layout editor theme doesn't match device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

Hopefully this is a nice easy one but it's currently making UI design suck even more than usual.

When I view my fragment's XML file in Android Studio's layout editor it shows up like so:
[image]

However when I view it on a device/emulator it correctly shows like this:
[image]

I have my custom theme selected up the top of the editor so in theory it should be used to render the UI. My only thought is that most of the components that are failing to render are part of `com.google.android.material` and that this isn't handled correctly by AS.

Is there a way to fix this or is it just the joys of using custom components?

Thanks

```
Path.op() not supported
```

```
java.awt.geom.IllegalPathStateException: missing initial moveto in path definition
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D$Double.needRoom(Path2D.java:1193)
    at java.awt.geom.Path2D.closePath(Path2D.java:1877)
    at android.graphics.Path_Delegate.close(Path_Delegate.java:824)
    at android.graphics.Path_Delegate.nClose(Path_Delegate.java:329)
    at android.graphics.Path.nClose(Path.java)
    at android.graphics.Path.close(Path.java:508)
    at com.google.android.material.shape.ShapeAppearancePathProvider.calculatePath(ShapeAppearancePathProvider.java:123)
    at com.google.android.material.shape.ShapeAppearancePathProvider.calculatePath(ShapeAppearancePathProvider.java:83)
    at com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable.calculateStrokePath(MaterialShapeDrawable.java:1142)
    at com.google.android.material.shape.MaterialShapeDrawable.draw(MaterialShapeDrawable.java:940)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.CutoutDrawable.draw(CutoutDrawable.java:88)
    at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:20412)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20198)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20177)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20077)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20075)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20210)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20177)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.draw(TextInputLayout.java:3623)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20077)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:2023)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20075)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20075)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1277)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20075)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20075)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20210)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20177)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:399)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:551)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:420)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.render(BridgeRenderSession.java:120)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:151)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:133)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$null$8(RenderTask.java:783)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

```
The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate: 
- Paint.setLetterSpacing() not supported. (Ignore for this session) 
- Paint.setShadowLayer is not supported. (Ignore for this session)
```

Comment: Don't you have some warning like `Render failed`? Android studio sometimes can't properly render the view - usually restarting the whole IDE works. Secondly, what is the API difference between your device and emulator? (if any)

Comment: Its works on both the device and emulator (and they are the same version). There are some render errors (I've updated the question with them). I've tried doing a restart and invalidating the cache which didnt help. Thanks for your help

Comment: One way to solve Path.op() error is adding `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'` to your dependencies (if you have that implementation already, still - replace yours with that alpa02)

Comment: Huh, that's fixed it (I was on alpha04). So I guess this is just something that they broke at some stage then? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, it might be a bug or they just deleted support for that. I will post this as an answer, so please mark it as an correct answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace your material implementation to

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'`

Path.op() do not work on version newer than alpa02 - it might be a bug or they just deprecated it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, UI design is slightly easier when you can see the elements :)